# How do I get kopete to hide/ignore status changes?

Tags: kde, kopete

I'm tired of kopete showing me every time someone goes away, online, it's annoying as it doesn't matter to me. How do I get kopete to hide these messages, or at least not alert me to them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one is well hidden :-)

**To remove the KDE event notification**

1. Go to KDE system settings
2. Select "Application and System Notifications".
3. Choose Kopete Messenger in Event source,
4. Select "Status Change" and uncheck all options.

**To remove the event in the Kopete chat window**

1. In Kopete, go to menu Settings / Configure...
2. Select Behavior / Chat
3. Uncheck "Show events in chat window".

Comment: but this doesn't actually prevent kopete from printing the status changes in the chat window

Comment: @xenoterracide I thought the word "alert" referred to the notification. you may want to clarify what you meant (e.g., hide these messages in the chat window).

Comment: I just added another option in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to configure what you do and don't get notified about by Kopete and how it notifies you by going to Settings->Configure Notifications.

Comment: but this doesn't actually prevent kopete from printing the status changes in the chat window.